# Why this recursive function is throwing StackOverFlow error???this is my logic for binary search and Where is the exact point of error in it

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

This is my logic for binary search and when I try to run it it gives 
me error of stackoverflow....I have written base condition also. Where is the exact point of error in it.
For this code, I have taken global array with predefined value and given startingIndex=0 initially and lastIndex=intArray.length-1;

```
public static void binarySearchInteger(int searchingElement,int 
   startingIndex,int lastIndex) {
    middleIndex=(startingIndex+lastIndex)/2;
    if(searchingElement==intArray[middleIndex])
        System.out.println("Found the Element");
    else if(startingIndex==lastIndex&&
                            searchingElement!=intArray[middleIndex])
        System.out.println("There is no such Element");
    else {
        if(intArray[middleIndex]>searchingElement)
            binarySearchInteger(searchingElement,
                                           startingIndex,middleIndex);
        else
          binarySearchInteger(searchingElement,middleIndex,lastIndex);
    }           
}
```

Comment: what values do you have? did you debug? how big is your array?

Comment: Is your array sorted?

Comment: Debug your code.

Comment: If this isn't an exercise to learn about binary search operations, you might just use `java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(int[] array, int key)` instead

Comment: The recursive calls must always have lesser ranges: startingIndex..middleIndex and middleIndex..lastIndex.

Comment: better to show all the code and what is your input. improve your question as comments say.

Comment: my array is this [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10] and when i search for 10 or no which is not there then it throws error of stackoverflow else it does not......and i didn't debug

Comment: Try `else if ( startingIndex >= lastIndex &&`...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto what you suggested didn't changed anything....still there is error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose `startIndex == 0` and `endIndex == 1`, then `middleIndex` is set to `1 / 2 == 0` (integer division). Now `startIndex == middleIndex`, so your last recursive call will can the method with the exact same parameter values and cause an infinite recursion, which will lead to a stack overflow.

Since you are already comparing with the middle element, you don't need to include the middle element in the recursive searches, so replace the last recursive call with:

```
binarySearchInteger(searchingElement,middleIndex + 1,lastIndex);
```

There might be more errors in your code, but this one I found by only looking at it. You can find errors yourself by using a debugger and stepping through your code, looking exactly at what happens.